# How to correctly pin the users folder to the sidebar after changing their location from the C drive to the D drive

Tags: windows-10

I've changed the location of the library folders from the default C drive to the D drive.

When I pin the music library folder quick search, which is in the D drive, it pins a music library folder with the location on the C drive, which doesn't even exist; it I try to unpin it, it doesn't work; the only way it unpins is if I create the music folder on the C drive and change the location of the music folder that is on D to the C drive again.

This behavior's happening on the music and videos folder, but not on the documents, downloads, pictures or desktop folder.

The following error appears when I click the pinned folder on the quick access: [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yUtHB.png) and the folder looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GqCPT.png); the location appears to point toward the C drive, but I clicked on pin on the folder of the D drive.

What can I do?

Comment: The solution for the supposed duplicate is deleting the CustomDestinations file. I think this might relate to User Shell Folder entries in the registry.